# ReactJS - Changing color of component dynamically when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to using React for building a website and I'm having a bit of an issue trying to figure out how to dynamically change the background of a div when a radio button is clicked.

In my latest attempt to get a unit example of what I want to get done, I've produced the following code:

```
const statuses = {
  "submitted": "blue"
}
style = {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Employer">
        <h2>Employer</h2>
        <div className="status-wrapper">
          <div className="status-option">
            <input type="radio" value="progress" name="option" onChange={e => this.style['backgroundColor'] = statuses[e.target.value]} style={this.style}></input>
            <label>In Progress</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And my main component along with the state is the following:

```
state = {
  postings: [{
    id: 1,
    style: {backgroundColor: 'yellow'},
    name: "Google",
    status: 0
  }]
}

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Employer postings = {this.state.postings}></Employer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The code results in a "TypeError: 'backgroundColor' is read-only" error, which I imagine could be the result of not properly updating the state of the component.

If anyone could help me get a handle on this and hopefully help me learn more about React in the process, I would be much appreciative!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you give us a little bit more information, please? For example, you are passing `postings` prop to your component but you never use it. Are you mapping this prop in another component and pass it to an `Employer` component? Is the first component this one? Also, you are saying you want to change the color of a `div` but you are applying the style to your `input`. By the way, you should use state and get the benefit from it. This makes React nice.

Comment: Hello, thank you! The postings prop was mapped within the main App component that the second snippet of code is from and it was being passed into Employer in a fruitless attempt to read from the posting's style attribute and edit it. I instead replaced it with what is currently in the onChange section. The main component is the second snippet and the only other component I have is Employer which is in a separate file. I see what you're saying about the input, I'm not sure why I put it in there :-) Any good resource you could recommend for understanding state more?

Comment: You are welcome. I see now. Ok then, when you give your code always put the necessary parts :) You can save time like this and get quicker answers :) If @prasanth's answer is not enough for you just comment about it. [The official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) is very good :) Just go through it if you haven't done yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are update `this.style` is not state object .So do with `this.setState()` function call .And also change style with `this.state.style`

```
Changer = e => {
let val = e.target.value;
this.setState(state => {
  state.style.backgroundColor = statuses[val];
  return state;
});
};
```

For input side

```
 <input type="radio"
              value="progress"
              name="option"
              onChange={this.Changer}
              style={{ ...this.state.style }}
            />
            <label style={{ ...this.state.style }}>In Progress</label>
```

Check this **[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-almeida-53mes)**

1. First thing if you are using class.So better use constructor instead of plain `state`
2. you are setting the color to input radio button.But is not visible the color. so fix with label its working
3. For changing style with entire object use spread operater for copy the object to style of element `{...object}`

Comment: I attempted this and I received a "TypeError: this.state is null" error.

It is worth mentioning that the two snippets of code are in different files and I was under the impression that components that are not in the main components scope can not directly interact with state. Again, I'm not super familiar with React, so I could totally be off base on that so any clarification would be awesome.

Comment: can you post full code or working sanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new .Because i don't what way you are using hooks function or class in react

Comment: Sure! I just uploaded my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sea-8wysi). Cool tool by the way, I'll definitely be using this in the future.

Comment: Upvoted. Just one thing, you don't need to `bind` the `Changer` method. You are already defining it as an arrow function.

Comment: One more thing :) When setting the state using spread operator would be nice instead of setting the state directly like this. I know you are using the callback but still :) For example: `this.setState(state =>({
      style: {
        ...state.style,
        backgroundColor: statuses[val],
      }
    }))`

Comment: Ya .you are right @devserkan.But OP still very new be to react and js. For inline call very harmful to understand

Comment: This is why we should give the "right" examples :) They should learn the optimal and right way. Never, ever change your state as setting its value directly. All newcomers should get used to it I guess :)

Comment: if you need to right better edit my answer and sandbox also

Comment: Much appreciated prasanth and devserkan, this solution worked perfectly. Although I am not new to programming or even JavaScript, React is still quite new to me and it's clear I've still got a bit of learning to do :) Thanks folks!

Comment: Editing other's answers is not so suitable, this is why I'm dropping those comments :) But of course, those are just comments, you can keep your way if you think it is better.

Comment: @devserkan .i don't tell this is better one .it's enough for that op question. Because in op question his just replace the entire object not appending with previous one